# Dynamic Layer Name - Leaflet Layer Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layers

I would like to have the name of a layer used by Leaflets layer control feature come from a variable instead of a string and based on data from the layer. The example shown below uses the variable layerName.

Is this even possible since it is expecting a name value pair? Is there a work around?

```
var layerName = feature.properties.condition[0];

//layer control
var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
    "Aerial Imagery": MapQuestOpen_Aerial
};

var overlayMaps = {
    layerName: layer1,

};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Leaflet [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-config), the layer config is an object literal with layer names as keys and layer objects as values.

That means you can use `[]` to set the object key, here is the modified codes:

```
var layerName = feature.properties.condition[0];

//layer control
var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
    "Aerial Imagery": MapQuestOpen_Aerial
};

//create the layer config object first
var overlayMaps = {
    //layerName: layer1,
};

//add the layer to the overlayMaps with a dynamic layer name
overlayMaps[layerName] = layer1;

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```